# Credentials for the SQL Server Agent service are invalid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 development server on my local machine as administrator.

During the installation I receive this error, any idea how to solve it?thanks

> *[Error Message]
>
>   The credentials you provided for the SQL Server Agent service are invalid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the SQL
>   Server Agent service.*
>
> *[Details]
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Agent.InputValidationException: The credentials you provided for the SQL Server Agent service are
>   invalid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the SQL
>   Server Agent service.*

Comment: thanks mar_s for your editing!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved using as credential built-in accounts as the NetworkService 
this article point me out in the right direction
http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2008_0013.htm

Answer (score 22):

Use the credential that you use to login to PC. Username can be searched by Clicking in sequence

> Advanced -> Find -> Choose your Username -> (e.g. JOHNSMITH_HP/John)
>
> Password must be same as your windows login password

There you go !!

Comment: I wasn't able to find my username via that sequence, but found it by looking in the Users folder.  Which is worth noting as, if you're using a MS account to login to windows, your username on the computer is not what actually appears on Windows' login screen.

Answer (score 9):

1. Under the "Account Name" Drop Box choose Browse. 
   Type the user name that you used to log in to windows on the
   "Enter the object name to select" and then click "Check Names".
   Click "Ok".
2. Under "Password" just type the password that you used for windows login.

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was more of a Microsoft bug, than an actual issue. I installed under the Administrator login and used strong password btw but I was still getting this error constantly.

I tried to install with Windows credential without entering the password, but that did not go through either. Was getting the same error.

**Then I cleared all password textboxes *manually* and copies the correct password in *each* text box. Hit enter, and it went through.**

The error was most likely misleading.

Comment: This is exactly the same issue that I've had. Thought i was going mad for a second!

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be several problems that can cause this symptom. To tell them apart, one needs to look in [the setup log files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx) in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\[versionnumber]\Setup Bootstrap\Log`, probably `Detail.txt`.

According to [this article](http://blog.basefarm.com/blog/sql-server-2008-r2-setup-fails-due-to-invalid-credentials/), when running the installer as a local administrator and trying to use a domain account for the service, it may claim that the credentials are invalid because the local administrator does not have sufficient permissions in the domain to look up the service account's SID. This was the main problem I was encountering, and it might be what was affecting the original poster a year and a half ago.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error as a result of trying to use a cloned VM that had the same SID as the domain.  The two options to fix it were: sysprep (or rebuild) the database server OR dcpromo the DC down and back up to change the domain SID.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to be logged in as a domain user.

It gave me this error when I was logged in as local machine Administrator and trying to add domain service account.

Logged in as domain user (but admin on machine) and it accepted the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In my case password was expired. Change the password and try the step again.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have been battling to understand why, when at the Account section of the installation of a second node, the system will not accept the password I used to log in. I have been scratching my head - reading every post under the sun all to no avail.

I did notice that some service accounts were given as `service.instname.instno@FDNdomain.com` and others were given as `DOMAIN\service.instname.instno` (the latter being the Win2000 version)

I also noticed comments about strength of password so I thought - I can do that so I changed the password to a much higher strength and RDC in to the server - with new password and thought - best to update the services on the existing node first. I stopped the service, clicked on password and pasted in from the clipboard - (can't go wrong eh?) ha ha says Windows.. Got ya.. it wouldn't accept the password - that I just logged in with. I clicked on browse to select the service account and VOILA! the account name changed to the `DOMAIN\user` version and readily accepted the password. I then repeated the exercise on the other service. I then found that the node installation would continue (after backing up and forward through the process) to pick up the new name format and accepted the passwords without complaint.

I think the moral of this experience is to use the wizards and select through the "browse" button rather than manually entering the service name.

I hope my experience saves someone else the pain I went through.

Still Confused

Answer (score 0):

I had a domain account with a strong password, but it didn´t work, then I used Network Service account. I tried to change it on SQL Server Configuration Manager after installation and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Taking SQL Server cluster role offline-Online on node 1 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a VM that was server 2012 and I had to change the nic to VMXNET 3. It wasn't connecting to the domain fast enough for the services to start I guess.

Answer (score 0):

the button 'Use same account' below thee main window will fill in all the textboxes automatically. this worked fpr me.

Answer (score 0):

You might encounter one of these three problems:

- Password Policy Violation, find valuable information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959.aspx
- Password not starting with a "character"
- Domain Service User's account might be locked.

A blog post with the summary for all three possible problems might be found here:
https://cms4j.wordpress.com/2016/11/29/0x851c0001-the-credentials-you-provided-for-the-sqlserveragent-service-is-invalid/