# Unable to install Sql Server 2008 R2 developer

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing issues while installing 'Sql Server 2008 R2 developer' edition. My OS is windows 8. I am getting the error 
"This program has compatability issues. Microsoft Sql Server 2008 and 2008 R2". I went through the solutions online for this issue.I installed 'VS 2010'. I enabled 'dotnet framework 3.5' which is under 'Turn windows features on or off' in programs menu of control panel. I installed 'Sql Server 2008 SP3' before installing 'Sql Server 2008 R2'. But same issue arised. Then I uninstalled 'Sql Server 2008 SP3' and installed 'Sql Server 2008 R2 SP2' before installing 'Sql Server 2008 R2'. But there is no use. My windows updates are up to date. I am strggling with this issue for 3 days. I need your suggestions.

Comment: There should be an option on the Compatibility Issues warning to carry on regardless (can't remember the exact wording). Have you tried using that option?

Comment: I did that. But after some steps I am getting the error "The credentials you provided for the SQL Server Agent service are invalid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the SQL Server Agent service".

Comment: Thanks Mr.Damien. The credential issue is also solved by reading this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932573/credentials-for-the-sql-server-agent-service-are-invalid